# Users disappeared from wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin, users, login

I have a WordPress multisite network and the question is related to one of my sites on that network. The site has a login page before you can use that site.

So I created a user from wp-admin with the Subscriber role.

The idea was to let that user log in to the site but not have access to wp-admin, but it didn't work.

So I went in again as a Superadmin and changed the role to " - No role for this website - ".

It worked and that user can't access wp-admin but can still log in to the site.

Now I want to edit that user's information, but the user disappeared from the list shown in wp-admin.

My question is:

**Where do I find that user?**

Some follow-up questions: is it removed but still active? How come? Is there a specific location where I could find that user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll find the user in network admin => users

Comment: Thank you didnt think that far lol. So basicly they are still users but with no permission right ?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. They can't even login.

Comment: See the can still login to the site , but do not acces wp-admin

Answer (score 0):

This will help because the User might be still unconfirmend!

https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-find-pending-unconfirmed-users-in-wordpress/

And/Or just install this PlugIn: https://wordpress.org/plugins/unconfirmed/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/256133)